# what is the meaning of $a_n$ grows as for example $O(n\log n)$ or $O(n^2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Given a positive and increasing sequence $\{a_n\}$, what is the meaning of $a_n$ grows as for example $O(n\log n)$ or $O(n^2)$. I have read this in some books but the google search did not yield anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is the *Big O* or *Landau-Notation* which is explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations). In this example you can define a function

$$f: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(n):=a_n$$

and for example $a_n$ grows $O(n^2)$ now means that there are constants $k, n_0$ such that $$\forall n>n_0 \; |f(n)| \leq |n^2\cdot k|$$

Comment: I would have said: $|f(n)| \le k\;n^2$.

Comment: I am sorry you are right of course I was confused with tex :-)

Answer (score 3):

Please see [this Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)